# Load another web page on click of a CSS box. CSS or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got several CSS boxes on one of my Google Sites pages which wrap themselves around a js slider.

I'm wanting to link to another page on my site through the click on the box rather than by clicking on the text within the box.

I've done a bit of research and I haven't had much luck. Some say it's doable in CSS, some say javascript.

I've tried switching around the  tag to be outside the  but this completely breaks my slider.

I've got a snippet of my code below:

**Style (CSS)**

```
 .box1 {
   background: ##ffd700;
   border-radius: 6px;
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   transition-property: background;
   transition-duration: 1s;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   z-index:2;
 }
.box1:hover {
   background: #990033;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target = "_self"><font color = #ffffff>Google</font></a></div>
```

I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyh44dub/

Would I be required to add more javascript to my code or is there a possible way of doing this through the CSS?

Note: I've got a grand total of 8 boxes created.

Comment: font tag has be deprecated for ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added it to your JSFiddle. No need to restructure your HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/tyh44dub/2/

```
.box1 a{
      position:absolute;
      display:block;
      top:0px;
      bottom:0px;
      left:0px;
      right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your a tag to the outside of the Div that will make the whole div clickable for your link.

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_self"><div class="box1"><font color = #ffffff>Google</font>
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the div with the anchor tag; instead putting the anchor inside the div.

Demo here

```css
 .box1 {
     background: #ffd700;
     border-radius: 6px;
     cursor: pointer;
     height: 100px;
     line-height: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     transition-property: background;
     transition-duration: 1s;
     transition-timing-function: linear;
     width: 100px;
     position: relative;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     z-index:2;
 }
 .box1:hover {
     background: #990033;
 }
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_self"><div class="box1"><font color = #ffffff>Google</font>
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the anchor to be the fill the whole element, set the anchor to be a block element

```
.box1 > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside the a tag is clickable and links to an href, all you have to do is place the div tag inside the a tag like this:

```
    <a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target = "_self"><div class="box1" 


     style="color:#ffffff">Google</div></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the W3Schools is removing HTML tags that were used for formatting elements, leaving that aspect to CSS.

Secondly, you could probably use that idea as a button with an onclick event, such as this:

### Html

```
<button onclick="click()">Click me!</button>
```

### Javascript

```
function click() {
window.location("www.google.com");
};
```

You don't need to remove the link/button from the div.